# Does split-screen count towards Professor Portal?

Tags: steam, portal-2

I have completed co-op online and have the "You Saved Science" achievement. If I play with someone who has played **offline** co-op do I still get "Professor Portal"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they can't have played co-op at all; the point is for you, as Professor Portal, to teach them how to play co-op (so online/offline is irrelevant).  See this for confirmation: http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/portal-2/achievement/51218-Professor-Portal.html#56